# My output is correct but i don't understand my output

Tags: c, dynamic-programming, towers-of-hanoi

This my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int move_disks(int, char, char, char);

int main()
{
    int num;
    char a='A',b='B',c='C';
    printf("Enter the number of disk: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    printf("\nThe sequence of movement of disks are:\n");
    move_disks(num, a, b, c);

    return 0;
}

int move_disks(int num, char source_peg, char aux_peg, char to_peg)
{
    if(num == 1)
    {
        printf("\nMove disk 1 from peg %c to peg %c.", source_peg, to_peg);
        return;
    }
    move_disks(num - 1, source_peg, to_peg, aux_peg);
    printf("\nMove disk %d from peg %c to peg %c.", num, source_peg, to_peg);
    move_disks(num - 1,aux_peg,  source_peg, to_peg);

}
```

And my output is this:

```
Enter the number of disk: 3

The sequence of movement of disks are:

Move disk 1 from peg A to peg C.
Move disk 2 from peg A to peg B.
Move disk 1 from peg C to peg B.
Move disk 3 from peg A to peg C.
Move disk 1 from peg B to peg A.
Move disk 2 from peg B to peg C.
Move disk 1 from peg A to peg C.
```

In output, in line " Move disk 1 from peg C to peg B." I can't understand how this is happening because  in my code in recursion function in if statement "printf("\nMove disk 1 from peg %c to peg %c.", source_peg, to_peg);" this is the print statement , and in any recursive call I never pass  "peg C" as source peg.

Comment: Google _tower of hanoi_, you'll find tons of information.

Answer (score 2):

Your initial call from the `main` function is

```
move_disks(num, a, b, c);
```

Here you pass `c` as the functions `to_peg` argument.

In the very first recursive call you do

```
move_disks(num - 1, source_peg, to_peg, aux_peg);
```

Here the `to_peg` is passed to the recursive call as the `aux_peg`.

And later you will call:

```
move_disks(num - 1,aux_peg,  source_peg, to_peg);
```

Where you use `aux_peg` as the `source_peg` to the recursive call.

So after a few calls the `c` peg will indeed become the source (`c` -> `to_peg`, `to_peg` -> `aux_peg`, `aux_peg` -> `source_peg`).

---

All this should have been very clear if you learn how to use a *debugger* to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

I also recommend using pen and paper while debugging to make it easier to follow along.